# How Android executables are built?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to write a program for an executable which is similar to dumpsys. I have created a .cpp file and an Android.mk file. However, when I run `ndk-build` on either programs, I get compilation error. On the other hand, the same dumpsys program is built correctly when I compile the whole Android source.

The first error I get is
`fatal error: utils/Log.h: No such file or directory`. Then I have to use `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` to solve this.

Next, I get undefined reference to *methods* errors like undefined reference to android::String16::String16().

After that, I link some objects like String16.o to solve this issue. But some of them depend on other objects and I have to add the one by one. I don't know how Android build compiles dumpsys without facing such issues.

How is ndk-build different from compiling the whole Android source? What is the right way to build if I want to compile a standalone project?

Comment: "I get compilation error" - which one?

Comment: @Esavier First, it cannot find some of the libraries included in dumpsys.cpp such as utils/Log.h, so I have to add LOCAL_C_INCLUDES to solve this error. Afther that, I get errors like undefined referece to android::String16::String16(), so I used the object files of my compiled source to solve this issue. But, it seems that I'm stuck in an infinite loop and have to add more objects every time I add a new object to consider its dependencies.

Comment: The same code for dumpsys is compiled smoothly when I compile the whole source code and without adding any of the files I have to add to my own project. Even if I run ndk-build for dumpsys, it will return the same errors.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I added some details to the original post. Thanks

Comment: ndk-build is for building a native (.so) library to be used in an Android application project.  The Android source tree build does not use ndk-build for native executables.

Comment: @RichardCritten I guess ndk-build can be used to create native executables by writing `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)` but it doesn't work for my project or dumpsys itself when I run ndk-build.

Comment: @Mahdi ndk-build uses a much smaller "supported" build environment (see the NDK docs).  Most of the full build environment under android source is not supported and can not be used by ndk-build.

Comment: @RichardCritten I see. So if I want to write a program that requires the full build environment, what should I do?